# Nginx responds 200 ok while no data returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, nginx, puma

I am using **rails api** with **puma** as an application server and **React js** as frontend with **nginx** server as web server. The problem is while I make an api request, for couple of times the server responds with data in json format.
But, after certain request, the web server responds with `status 200` ok with no data.When I try to access my data as response.data, I get `response.data=""`

Request Headers 
[image]

Response Header
[image]

Api request

```
function fetchHolidays(year) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'access-token': Cookie.get('accesstoken'),
        'client': Cookie.get('client'),
        'uid': Cookie.get('uid'),
        'expiry': Cookie.get('expiry'),
        'token-type': Cookie.get('tokentype')
             }
  }
  return axios(`${baseURL.URL}${baseURL.PORT}/api/v1/holidays`,
              requestOptions).then(response => {
         return response
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code to your answer please.

Comment: Code added as above.

Comment: and your controller method?

Comment: Possible that your token is expiring?

Comment: The thing is, if I had missed something in the header section regarding token or my token had expired I would get 401 Unauthorized, but in my case I am getting 200 ok. Recently I just checked my log and found that, nginx server it self is rendering the request with 200 ok instead of forwarding it to application server.